# Plesk: Enable mail.domain.tld as Incoming/Outgoing Mail-Server

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I'm not quite sure, if it is possible to change the default mail-server aliases for Incoming/Outgoing mail on Plesk 10.4 ?

By default, Plesk Panel uses **imap.domain.tld** / **pop.domain.tld** and **smtp.domain.tld** since Plesk 7+.

It seems not to be possible to setup changes in the panel.

I've successfully completed several migrations for some old hosts from Plesk 7 to 10.4, **but some customers don't** want to edit their Outlook preferences (they still use mail.domain.tld) ...

regards

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, the documentation doesn't really cover this in much detail.  It looks like there is a DNS template that gets applied to all tenants.  It seems like you would want to update the template and/or create a new one that uses the DNS names you want when a tenant is created.

Regardless the imap.domain.tld/pop/smtp format has become pretty standard these days and makes things a lot cleaner, especially if you ever end up using multiple boxes to handle each function.

Comment: DNS template would impact all customers on the server. If one or few customers needs additional aliasing, their individual DNS zone could be edited.